# Database error using new version on upgrade

Tags: android, database

I am adding a column to a DB in the `onUpgrade()` method which works fine on devices / emulators where the previous DB version exists.

However when installing on devices for first time 
I get an error starting the column (in on upgrade()) can't be found.

I am assuming this is because the device can't find a previous version so the `onUpgrade()` is not executed.

Is there a way around this?

Cheers

Here is the code:

```
@Override 
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        // only called once when DB first created, takes DB as arg
        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE "+ DATABASE_TABLE + " ("+
        KEY_ROWID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
        KEY_DIVELOCATION + " TEXT , "+ 
        KEY_DIVESITE + " TEXT , " +
        KEY__DIVENUMBER + " INTEGER DEFAULT 0 , " +
        KEY__DIVEDATE + " TEXT , " +
        KEY_DIVERATING + " FLOAT DEFAULT 0.0 , " +
        KEY_BOTTOMTIME + " INTEGER DEFAULT 0 , " +
        KEY_DIVEBUDDY + " TEXT , " +
        KEY__DIVECENTER + " TEXT , " +
        KEY_ENDBAR + " INTEGER DEFAULT 0 , " +
        KEY_STARTBAR + " INTEGER DEFAULT 0 , " +
        KEY_VIZIBILTY + " INTEGER DEFAULT 0 , " +
        KEY_WATERTEMP + " INTEGER DEFAULT 0, " +
        KEY_COMMENTS + " TEXT , " +
        KEY_CONDITIONS + " TEXT , " +
        KEY_DIVEPICTURE + " TEXT );"
        );
        //use for dtabase querys
        columns = new String[]{KEY_ROWID, KEY_DIVERATING, KEY_BOTTOMTIME, KEY_DIVEBUDDY, 
                KEY__DIVECENTER, KEY_DIVELOCATION,
                KEY__DIVENUMBER, KEY_DIVESITE, KEY_ENDBAR, KEY_STARTBAR, 
                KEY_VIZIBILTY, KEY_WATERTEMP,KEY__DIVEDATE, 
                KEY_COMMENTS, KEY_CONDITIONS, KEY_DIVEPICTURE};



    }//end onCreate DB inner helper class

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        // if table exits, drop it (delete) and recreate it to upgrade it
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + DATABASE_TABLE);
        onCreate(db);
        //need to call upgrade and add a int column for depth, newVersion is 2
        if (newVersion> oldVersion ){
            db.execSQL("ALTER TABLE "+DATABASE_TABLE+" ADD COLUMN "+KEY_DEPTH+" INTEGER DEFAULT 0");
        }
```

Comment: you should modify the code in the `onCreate()` also since there are devices that don't have your application installed.

Comment: Post your onCreate method code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

onUpgrade will be only called when a version of database will gets old. i.e you change the version which you passes during database creation.

e.g

```
super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null,DATABASE_VERSION);
```

Now if DATABASE_VERSION is changed, only then onUpgrade will gets called...

So i think, you just need to execute your create table commands in `onCreate` and only use commands of changing tables in `onUpgrade`. That way you won't have this issue.

Hope it helps

Comment: I just moved the creation of new column to onCreate method and worked fine on devices with no previous DataBase versions. Thanks